# Best way to find min of element in tuple

Tags: scala

I have an Array of 3-tuples in scala as such: `(a:Int, b:Int, val:Double)`, and I need to return an Array which has for all pairs `(a, b)` the minimum `val`. It is clear to me how to do this by going to a Map:

```
a.map(t => ((t._1,t ._2), t._3)).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).min).toArray
```

but I would like to avoid maps for the purposes of memory optimization. Is there a clean way to do this without Map?

Comment: You can look at the `.groupMapReduce` method, which may be faster (for instance see the implementation on [`Iterable`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.13.3/src/library/scala/collection/Iterable.scala#L617)).

Comment: Cool @Marth, thank you. But will not going through Map increase the load on GC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `groupMapReduce`, it does all the same, but in a single pass:

```
tuples.groupMapReduce(t => (t._1, t._2))(_._3)(_ min _)
```

Runnable example:

```
val tuples = List(
  (0, 0, 58),
  (1, 1, 100),
  (0, 0, 1),
  (0, 1, 42),
  (1, 0, 123),
  (1, 0, 3),
  (0, 1, 2),
  (1, 1, 4)
)

tuples.groupMapReduce(t => (t._1, t._2))(_._3)(_ min _).foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
((0,0),1)
((1,1),4)
((1,0),3)
((0,1),2)
```

It should strictly decrease the load on GC compared to your solution, because it doesn't generate any intermediate lists for the grouped values, and neither for those `map`ped grouped values in the `_.map(_._2)`-step in your original solution.

It does not completely eliminate the intermediate `Map`, but unless you can provide any more efficient structure for storing the values (such as a 2-D array for, by limiting the possible `a`s and `b`s to be relatively small & strictly positive), the occurrence of a `Map` seems more or less unavoidable.